# Can you pass a shipping address to Stripe Checkout in PHP?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-api-php

I'm using [Stripe Checkout API](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder) to direct a website user to make payment.

Is there a way to pass a shipping address to the hosted checkout page so it's gathered from the referrer rather then Stripe themselves?

```
function createSession()
{
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('[API_KEY_REDACTED]');
    
    $YOUR_DOMAIN = '[SITE_URL_REDACTED]';
    
    // Calculate price
    $price = 50;
    
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'billing_address_collection' => 'required',
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => [[
            'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'gbp',
                'unit_amount' => $price,
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'Product'
                ],
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success',
        'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel',
    ]);
    
    return json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
}
```

You can add the following line to make Stripe ask for a shipping address, but I want to pass this from the referrer instead.

```
'shipping_address_collection' => [
    'allowed_countries' => ['US', 'CA'],
],
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you would [create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) and provide their shipping [address](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-address), then [provide that existing Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#handling-existing-customers) when creating the Checkout session:

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'customer' => 'cus_123',
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. So just to clarify, what's the usual practise if I'm using 'checkout as guest' i.e. no login system, and the user wants to checkout a second time in the future. I assume I wouldn't want to create _another_ customer with the exact same information. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you don't provide a Customer reference, Stripe will create a Customer for you in your Stripe account, which will be associated with the Checkout session. You would just provide this same Customer id next time if you did not want another to be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shipping_address_collection](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection) as shown below:

```php
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  ...
  'shipping_address_collection' => [
    'allowed_countries' => ['US', 'CA'],
  ],
  ...
]);
```

Also, you can use [payment_intent_data.shipping](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-shipping) to pass a shipping address to **Shipping** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** as shown below. *This doesn't pass a shipping address to **Stripe Checkout** but does pass to **Shipping** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** and you cannot use both `shipping_address_collection` and `payment_intent_data.shipping` at the same time otherwise there is an error:

```php
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  ...
  'payment_intent_data' => [
    'shipping' => [
      'name' => 'John Smith',
      'address' => [
        'country' => 'USA',
        'state' => 'California',
        'city' => 'San Francisco',
        'line1' => '58 Middle Point Rd',
        'line2' => '',
        'postal_code' => '94124'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  /*
  'shipping_address_collection' => [
    'allowed_countries' => ['US', 'CA'],
  ],
  */
  ...
]);
```

[image]